# how to reduce query redundancy?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an application using Laravel. Where I had to run a Query in different pages. So same Query i had to run in several controller. But i think this is not a good practice of coding ..Where can i write a single and execute it form several controller instead of writing it in again again? 
I know laravel eloquent and eager loading also. if i have a large query suppose joining two three tables how do i implement that?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  Are you asking for a way to avoid duplicating _code_ for the same query, or for a way to avoid running the same query multiple times?

Comment: avoid running the same query multiple times

Comment: What is the query doing?

Comment: Do you mean caching the results or reusing the code to perform the query?

Comment: sounds like you just made a definition of Query model in your application lol

Comment: @ThomasMoors I believe he answered that he wants the former.

Comment: *"So same Query i had to run in several controller"* -- there is not the responsibility of controllers to run queries. Their only job is to gather the resources (objects) needed to process the request, wire them together and tell one of them to do the actual job. If you have the same code in several constructors then move it into a new class responsible only with that task.

Comment: You just need to Cache the results for specific time, then the Cache will expire and run the query again. Laravel Cache facade can easily help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need create a new php-file in folder Helpers (app/Helpers) and put new class there. I use Main for example.

```
namespace App\Helpers;
class Main 
{
  static public function getSomething($id) {
         // ... DO something
         return var;
      }
}
```

Next you need add to config/app.php

```
    'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Main' => App\Helpers\Main::class
]
```

After that you can use from anywhere of your project

```
Main::getSomething($id);
```

with 'use App\Helpers\Main;' of course

This allows you to use this function in all controllers and not to repeat it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharing Data With All Views.

You can do so by sharing the data through the view Facade. With this every view will have access to the data. No need to query data from multiple controllers.

in you AppServiceProvider class > boot method

```
// write query
$query = User::all();

// Share data
View::share("user", $query);
```

Don't forget to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View at the top of the class

You can also use [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) to achieve similar scenario.